# Using builtin overflow functions with uint64_t types

Tags: c, gcc, built-in, integer-overflow

I am currently writing a program which makes heavy use of the `uint64_t` type, to enhance compatibility across platforms. 
As it happens, there are a lot of possibilities for overflows in my program, so I want to use the [built in overflow functions from gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html).

Unfortunately, they are only defined on `int`s, `long int`s, `long long int`s and so on. The `uintX_t` types guarantee to always be of size X bits, which is not the case for those types e.g. a `long int` is not guaranteed to be 64 bit. This makes me think, that the builtin overflow functions can't be used here.

How to solve this issue now?

I have two approaches:

1. using the `UINT64_MAX` constant from `stdint.h` and make the overflow prediction myself. However, I am not a friend of "re-inventing the wheel".
2. using the e.g. `__builtin_add_overflow_p` function to only check for the overflow. However, I am not 100% sure if they can be applied to `uint64_t`.

What is the best way? Am I overseeing something obvious?

Comment: Potentially have a function that returns bool for "this overflowed" could be useful. Of course using some GCC specific thing is not really great for compatibility. As far as `x86` goes, if I recall for **unsigned** purposes, the "Carry flag" can be used, I am not sure GCC exposes that however.

Comment: I would just try `__builtin_add_overflow` and let compiler sort out the types. It's extremely unlikely that `uint64_t` would exist but not match with `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`. Unless you want to be portable to every system ever made, I think it's close enough with modern implementations. If you need extra check, just add static assertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Using builtin overflow functions with `uint64_t`
>    ... to use the [built in overflow functions from gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html).

To form your own `builtin_uadd64_overflow()`, without "re-inventing the wheel", use `_Generic` to steer function selection.

```
#define builtin_uadd64_overflow(a,b,r) _Generic(*(r), \
  unsigned: __builtin_uadd_overflow, \
  unsigned long: __builtin_uaddl_overflow, \
  unsigned long long: __builtin_uaddll_overflow \
  )(a,b,r)
```

Comment: Hmmm, Link has "The first built-in function allows arbitrary integral types for operands and the result type must be pointer to some integral type other than enumerated or boolean type, the rest of the built-in functions have explicit integer types.", so [@user694733](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59373630/using-builtin-overflow-functions-with-uint64-t-types/59373844#comment104940301_59373630) idea looks even better.

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned overflow is defined behaviour according to the C standard (§6.2.5/9)

> A computation involving unsigned operands can never overﬂow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type.

So when you have an addition like;

```
uint64_t a, b, c;

c = a + b;
```

you can check, if the operation overflowed by testing

```
int overflowed = c < a || c < b;
```

Of course, you can wrap this into a function if you need.

Comment: Is not `int overflowed = c < a;` sufficient?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, you are correct, just added the other option to illustrate the symmetry. One of the two can be left out.

Answer (score 1):

The following functions should work pretty well for objects of type `int` or `long long`; on 32-bit platforms, the `int` functions will be much more efficient than approaches using `long long`; on 64-bit platforms, the `long long` functions will be as efficient as the `int` ones.

```
int safe_add1(int  *value, int  delta) {
    int val = *value;
    int sum = delta+(unsigned int)val;
    if (((sum ^ val) & (sum ^ delta)) < 0)
        return -1;
    *value = sum;
    return 0;
}
int safe_add2(long long  *value, long long  delta) {
    long long val = *value;
    long long sum = delta+(unsigned long long)val;
    if (((sum ^ val) & (sum ^ delta)) < 0)
        return -1;
    *value = sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that to guarding against overflow really efficiently would in many cases require a compiler to use integer overflow as an invitation to implement a conforming extension that would define integer overflow semantics in a way that was tight enough to meet program requirements, but loose enough to allow optimizations.  For example, if a program wants to compute `x+y > z` while ensuring that no overflows that would yield *numerically-wrong* behavior go undetected, and if a compiler knows that `x` and `z` will be equal, the optimal way to meet requirements would be to compute `y > 0`, since that behavior would be *numerically correct* whether or not `x+y` could be computed without overflow.

Unfortunately, unless compilers provide extensions to recognize such constructs, there will be no way to write particularly efficient overflow-checking code.